# Autokey software linux, error. I want use keyboard shorcut linux

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autokey

I have the next error.

> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/usuario/.config/autokey/autokey.log'

in autokey program. Can you help me?

Comment: Please translate your message so everybody can understand it. "Permiso denegado" means "Permission denied". Can you show us the permissions of that particular file and also tell us which user is the one trying to access to that file? Also, can you show us the command you run in order to obtain that error message?

Comment: autokey in the terminal